# Unable to delete object in Rails using Ajax

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

Noob here trying to create a simple note submit and delete app in Rails 4. I'm using Ajax to submit/delete, but cannot figure out why my object won't delete.

My Controller includes the following Delete method:

```
def destroy
    Note.find(params[:id]).destroy
    render :json => "Note deleted!"
end
```

My "Create" method is as follows:

```
def create
    note = Note.create(title: note_params[:title], description: "click to add description")
    render :json => note
end
```

In my application.js, I am using Ajax to submit and then concurrently create a "Delete" button as such:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("form").submit(function(){
  $.post(
    $(this).attr('action'),
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
      console.log('Data Received from the Ajax call', data);
      //put additional codes here to update html, etc.
      //for example things like
      $('.all-notes').append(data.title);
      $('.all-notes').append('<input type="button" class="ajay" value="Delete">')
    },
    "json"
  );
  return false;
});
```

However, when I submit a note, I see a note with the associated delete button, but actually clicking on the button does nothing. Here is my Ajax code in the application.js file for delete:

```
  $(".ajay").submit(function(){
  $.post(
    $(this).attr('action'),
    $(this).serialize(),
    function(data){
      console.log('Data Received from the Ajax call', data);
      //put additional codes here to update html, etc.
      //for example things like
      $('.all-notes').remove(data.title);
    },
    "json"
  );
  return false;
});
```

Any thoughts? Much appreciated!

-A

Answer (score 0):

You should try something like this:

```
$('.ajay').live('click', function(){
    $.ajax({
        url: '/note/id',
        type: 'DELETE',
        success: function(result) {
            // Do something with the result
        }
    });
});
```